# castle windsor: how to use a Type as constructor property in xml config?

Tags: castle-windsor

I have the following:
    TypeUser:ITypeUser
    {
        public TypeUser(Type usedType){..}
    }

How do i configure the Type parameter in windsor config xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom types you need provide a type converter to handle the conversion, however "Type" is supported out of the box (if you take a look at the [list here on the castleproject site](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/typeconverters.html)) and should "just work" i.e. like so:

```
<component id="myServer" service="SomeNameSpace.ITypeUser, SomeAssembly" type="SomeNameSpace.TypeUser, SomeLib">
    <parameters>
        <usedType>SomeNameSpace.MyOtherType, SomeAssembly</usedType>
    </parameters>
</component>
```